# JWT Authentication using BackEnd and FrontEnd Approach

Tags: asp.net, jwt

I am trying to use JWT in order to secure authentication between two solutions (Back-End and Front-End).  The front end is obviously sending requests to the Back-End(API) and thus need to know how to pass the token with the request to the API.

I am very new to this JWT, so I would very much appreciate some guidance.

Answer (score 1):

You would want to pass the access token to the API via the HTTP authorization header value.   Here is the documentation for that header setting:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization